# Warning returning a captured reference from a lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I tried to use a lambda to conditionally bind a reference to one of two variables:

```
int foo, bar;
int &choice = [&]() -> int & {
    if (true /* some condition */) {
        return foo;
    } else {
        return bar;
    }
}();
```

This yields a warning in clang 3.4:

```
stack_stuffing.cpp:5:20: warning: reference to stack memory associated with
      local variable 'foo' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]
            return foo;
                   ^~~
stack_stuffing.cpp:7:20: warning: reference to stack memory associated with
      local variable 'bar' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]
            return bar;
                   ^~~
```

But I only ever return references to stack memory that's in scope where the lambda is called. Is this behavior specified, unspecified, or a clang bug?

Comment: Is there any particular reason to not use `int& choice = some_condition? foo: bar`? I'd think the compiler shouldn't warn, though.

Comment: @DietmarKühl The actual code `switch`es on an enum and I want the compiler to warn about unhandled cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed a bug in Clang - you are correctly capturing both variables by reference and no dangling references are created. I presume Clang automatically issued a warning every time someone returned a reference to a stack variable inside anything, be it a lambda or a function.

Clang 3.5 [does not show this warning anymore](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f171db44bca57a6), [neither does GCC 4.9.0](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b6af9a39bea0faf).

Comment: And gcc 4.7.1 doesn't warn.