# Clang warning when returning a lambda-capturing lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, clang++

The following (simplified) code trying to wrap a lambda gives me a warning with some Clang versions, but not all and not gcc.

```
template<typename Lambda>
auto wrapLambda(Lambda lambda)
{
    return [&lambda]() {
        lambda();
    };
}

auto wrappedLambda = wrapLambda([](){ return 0; });
```

```
warning: address of stack memory associated with parameter 'lambda' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]  
    return [&lambda]() {  
             ^~~~~~
```

Is this a bug, or am I missing something? I'm getting the warning with `x86-64 clang (trunk)` in [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/zaGGd51h8) and `clang version 11.1.0` as part of a larger repo, but I haven't been able to isolate the failure with that version.

The example in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744556/warning-returning-a-captured-reference-from-a-lambda) doesn't give the warning.

---

Improved (I think) version:

```
template<typename Callable>
auto wrapCallable(Callable&& callable)
{
    return [callable = std::forward<Callable>(callable)]() {
        callable();
    };
}

auto wrappedCallable = wrapCallable([](){ return 0; });
```

This silences the warning with `x86-64 clang (trunk)` in [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/f46hKzYx7). I think it should safely work for any functor, anything I'm missing?

Comment: Can't check since GodBolt is currently down, but I guess it's because the lamba is passed by copy to the template function. Perferct forwarding should silence the issue

Comment: Note your link to godbolt is useless. You have forgotten to generate link (by clicking "Share"), which will lead to your code.

Comment: @Moia Perfect forwarding, or dropping the & in [&lambda] seems to silence the warning. I assumed the template parameter would resolve to capturing the Lambda by reference, silly in hindsight. I'm a bit confused about the perfect forwarding case though. For the example, wouldn't it resolve to rvalue reference and essentially be the same case I'm getting a warning about?

Comment: @Ramon rvalue reference in template argument is called perfect forwarding (with use of std::forward of course) because it always pass the right type depending of the input. Anyway for your first case accepting a function by copy is ok, but then just pass by copy and it will be fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is exactly same as for this code:

```cpp
SomeType& foo(int x)
{
    SomeType bar{x};
    return bar; // undefined behavior returning reference to local object
}
```

Your lambda is capturing local object by reference, so when you return it, this will lead to undefined behavior since, captured object is no longer alive.

Most probably program will crash when you use this lambda (not if you are unlucky).

So this is bug in your code, clang is complaining properly.

**Edit after question update:**
After updating question new code creates copy (or move copy) of argument to lambda. Result is that returned lambda do not carry reference to local variable, so it is fine now.

Comment: Other compilers/versions aren't buggy to not warn though. they just "miss" the opportunity.